# Performance issues with -viewWillAppear: method

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, viewwillappear

My app captures images into a `UICollectionView` and once I grab an image or delete one the `–viewWillAppear:` method is called.

And it makes the transitions really slow. I don't know why and I need some assistance.

This method is called almost after every action, so I need to make my app faster.

The actual code is:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];//lay fetchrequest
fetchrequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [CCCoreDataHelper manageObjectContext];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchphotos = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchrequest error:&error];

self.photos = [fetchphotos mutableCopy];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: I think you should look at your code design. Use lazy loading and and put heavy loading stuff off the main thread (load images in the background). It's slow because you do everything right now on the main thread (same thread as the GUI uses to render on screen). This might be an interesting article for your case. http://www.sebastianrehnby.com/blog/2013/05/20/using-background-fetching-with-core-data/

Comment: @Konrad77 on the other hand if he will do this in background the view will be loaded without outdated or improper data or event crash an application. There might be a reason why he do it not in -viewDidLoad but in -viewWillAppear

Comment: If i make it in viewdidload. When an image is grabbed It does not show up in the collection view. However, if i do it in viewwillappear, when image picker closes, view appears, so that the new image shows up